# Firebase ecommerce_purchase issue

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I'm using Firebase Analitycs to log e-commerce events. 
Code:

```
var parameters = [String: NSObject]()
parameters[kFIRParameterCurrency] = template.currency as NSString
parameters[kFIRParameterValue] = album.price! as NSNumber
parameters[kFIRParameterTransactionID] = transaction.id as NSString
parameters[kFIRParameterShipping] = template.shippingPrice as NSNumber
FIRAnalytics.logEvent(withName: kFIREventEcommercePurchase, parameters: parameters)
```

On Firebase console I can see that event is logged as expected

[image]

But for some reason purchase data is not displayed on Firebase dashboard

[image]

Thanks.